# Why string is immutable in java

Tags: java, string

I doubt Why strings are called immutable, because if give like this String s="hi" and in the next line, we give s="hello"  the value of s will change right please help me to understand anyone.

Comment: Because `"hi"` and `"hello"` are immutable; you are creating two distinct `String` instances and assigning them to a single **reference** variable. `final String s = "hi";` would make the `s` reference immutable.

Comment: It really doesn't matter why they are immutable. However, immutable objects work better with multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a String variable with a literal ("hi") like this:

```java
String s = "hi"
```

you actually create a String object with an array of characters underneath. `s` is only the reference to this object in memory. Java does not allow to change String object itself (internal array). You can only assign `s` another object (`s = "hello"`).

Let's say you have following:

```java
String s = "hi";
String s2 = s;
s = "hello";
```

Here you do not change `s2`. It is still the same, still points to the "hi". You only changed the `s`, now it points to new String object - "hello".

Answer (score 1):

A `String` variable contains a reference to a `String`.

So when you assign a new value to a `String` variable, you are changing the reference, not the `String` itself.

Or in another words, the assignment makes the variable refer to a different string without changing the original string in any way.  (It can't change the original string because strings are immutable.)

Answer (score 0):

Strings created using String class are immutable i.e. once created cannot be modified.
This may seem to be a serious restriction on String initially . However, that is not the case . If you alter the existing string the new string gets created in the pool of strings and old one gets discarded .
This is how the string class is designed , because the java developers realized that creating a new string is much more efficient than modifying the existing one.